# Intelligent RegEx Replacement

Tags: regex, replace

I'm setting up a system to parse a string with very specified syntax and fix user errors.  For example, the syntax requires dates in a m/d/yy format (no leading 0s), so I need to make the following substitutions:

- 10/01/13 -> 10/1/13
- 10/10/13 -> no change
- 10/1/13 -> no change
- 01/10/13 -> 1/10/13

I have a lot of rules like this by which I need to find *portions* of a string and fix those portions.  I can use RegEx to identify what needs to be corrected easily. For an easier example, I want to find `CBUx[2-9]`, but then I need to replace with something like this `CBU x [2-9]` (spaces around x if preceded by CBU and follwed by a digit). Example:

input text: "blah blah CBUx3"
matched: "CBUx3"
replace: "CBU x 3"
output text: "blah blah CBU x 3"

Is this possible?  Note that I'm fully aware I could write code to find the slashes and digits.  I'm specifically trying to do this with an "intelligence RegEx replace".  I have a lot of different types of corrections that I can match with RegEx, and I would like to avoid writing specific correction procedures for each.

Comment: What do you mean by intelligent regex? Do you mean you want to combine all rules in a single regex? **P.S.** I believe smartly written regex are always intelligent!

Comment: What language are you using? Btw, any system that thinks m/d/yyyy is "intelligent" is probably already in trouble. Better to convert from the parochial, quaint m/d/yyyy format used in only one country to ISO yyyy/mm/dd, or dd/mm/yyyy as used in the rest of the world

Comment: The "intelligent" is modifying the replacement, not the regex.  The point is I want to be able to specify the replacement string with a regex.  Hence my examples. Whether or not you like the date format I'm forced to use in this instance (I prefer ISO) is entirely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like that for the leading zeroes:

```
\b0+([1-9])
```

And replace with `$1` (or `\1` depending on the language, though `\1` is less common nowadays).

But something a bit better might be with the use of a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<![.,])\b0+([1-9])
```

So that the `0` in `10,001.002` are not changed to `10,1.2`.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/iH2uU9)

The word boundary, `\b`, makes sure that the `0` (or more) are at the beginning of the number and the negative lookbehind is for cases of decimals and thousand separators, assuming that you have have floating numbers in the string. Note that this will however prevent the removal of zeroes in a date format of `11.01.13`. A more complex regex can however be made with the assumption that such a date always have a least one number after a second dot (itself after 2 numbers since dates and months take at most 2 digits) without encountering anything other than other numbers, which makes the regex look like...

```
(?<![.,](?![0-9]{2}\.[0-9]))\b0+([1-9])
```

And which renders to something like [this](http://regex101.com/r/hQ0mU7).

---

For the `CBUx[2-9]`, you can use a capture group as well:

```
CBUx([2-9])
```

And replace with: `CBU x $1` (or `\1`)

---

There might be some tweaks I didn't consider for the leading zero removal part, but that's what I can think about right now.

Comment: Thank you - the documentation I'd seen on the grouping with () and replacing with $ was not very clear (or at least not so to a Regex novice).  You not only answered my immediate question, but I now understand the underlying logic!

Comment: @Dr.Drew You're welcome! If you need any more clarification, let me know and I'll try to explain as much as I can :)